# Can I reference what is being evaluated in a switch or if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Assume the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Weather(string cityName)
{
    if (cityName == null)
    {
        return View(await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName));
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Weather");
}
```

I would like to restructure the code to make use of a switch statement evaluating the expression `await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName)` and then referencing it in the cases without having to assign it. Is this possible in any way or can't the evaluated expression, here being an object, not be referenced in any way without assigning it first?

What I could do (making conditionals from the object rather than the string value being given:

```
WeatherConvertedObject w = await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName);
switch (w)
{
    case null: return RedirectToAction("Weather");
    case not null: return View(await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName));
}
```

What I want to do (somehow if it is possible?):

```
switch (await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName))
{
    case null: return RedirectToAction("Weather");
    case not null: return View(this);
        //this illustration simply a reference to the evaluated object - this won't compile
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in C# like what you're asking and the code you're attempting to write is not idiomatic.  The first case you present should be `return View(w);` in any scenario.

Comment: I'm so confused as to what's being asked here.

Comment: @IanKemp It is simply whether the switched or evaluated statement can be referenced in the subsequent block produced. It shouldn't be too hard to understand - the last block of code clearly illustrates what I want to do without it being possible this way. The line of thought goes that since the expression is currently being evaluated it must be stored somewhere in the memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not your code flow is correct, there are *many* ways of writing what you want, though `switch` isn't it. One way to do it would be something like this:

```
if(await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName) is { } weather)  // implied not null
    return View(weather);
return RedirectToAction("Weather");
```

You also have the ternary operator to write it as an expression, also based on pattern matching like above.

Edit: well, you can also write it with a `switch` statement (or expression) if you really want to:

```
switch (await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName))
{
    case null: return RedirectToAction("Weather");
    case { } weather: return View(weather);
}
```

Comment: The last block of code would not compile since a `weather` object hasn't actually been defined and this hits the question on spot - can I reference the statement being evaluated somehow just like a `this` keyword can be used for other cases (not possible in switch). It must be possible since it is stored in the memory somewhere with the object being evaluated

Comment: @Aleksandar: The `weather` object gets defined by the second `case` condition: it uses pattern matching to declare the variable.

Comment: @Aleksandar. The pattern `{ } weather` is an empty property pattern which checks for  "not null" and which assigns the value to the new variable `weather` if the result of the check `true`. I.e., it declares this variable.

Comment: I would use a switch expression: `return await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName) switch { { } weather => View(weather), _ => RedirectToAction("Weather") };` or a ternary expression: `return await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName) is { } weather ? View(weather) : RedirectToAction("Weather");`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You guys are marvelous - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you confused a lot of people by including a (probably incorrect) conditional on the `cityName` variable, and then proceeding to ignore that conditional when you described the behavior you're looking for in your switch statement.

You could rewrite your method like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Weather(string cityName)
{
    return cityName switch
    {
        not null when await _weatherService.GetWeather(cityName) is {} w => View(w),
        _ => RedirectToAction("Weather")
    };
}
```

Note that this fixes what I believe was an error in your original code by using the cityName when it is *not null*. I'm also using switch expressions rather than switch statements.

Comment: Well if they instead read the whole question they would understand what I was inquiring about. This question has nothing to do about the variable name `cityName` and I believe I am being quite clear about that

Comment: People who are very accustomed to answering Stack Overflow questions appeared confused in the comments on your question. I think it's presumptive to imply they just didn't read your whole question. I'm glad you got the answer you were looking for. I'm just saying in the future you might get there faster by narrowing down the details you share to the parts you care about.